# Synchronizing threads so files load consecutively in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have got to load the files and print the data in them, but the threads are all running in parallel so after a few seconds only the data from the last file is shown. There are a total of seven files and I am looping them to load.

Here is my code:

```
 public class thread extends Thread {

     private static final String String = null;
     static String file="Lab5File";
     static String output="test2.dat";
     static ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();


 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

  threadList = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int l=1;l<8;l++ )  
     {

        thread1111 x = new thread1111(file+l+".dat");
        threadList.add(x);
        x.start();
     }

     try {
         int ch = System.in.read();

     } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

 } 


 public static class thread1111 extends Thread {
    String name ; 

    static DataOutputStream dos ;
    static FileOutputStream fos;
    static ArrayList<Thread> threadList;


    public thread1111(String fileName)
    {
        name = fileName;

          try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("test2.dat");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

    }

    public void run(){  

         InputStream is = null;
         DataInputStream dis = null;

         System.out.println("TRYING.........");

         try{

            // create input stream from file input stream
            is = new FileInputStream(name);

            // create data input stream
            dis = new DataInputStream(is);

        while (true) synchronized(dos)  {

                int Zip = dis.readInt();
                String City = dis.readUTF();
                String State = dis.readUTF();
                double Longitude =dis.readDouble();
                double Latitudes=dis.readDouble();
                int Zone = dis.readInt();
                int dst = dis.readInt();

                dos.writeInt(Zip);
                dos.writeUTF(City);
                dos.writeUTF(State);
                dos.writeDouble(Longitude);
                dos.writeDouble(Latitudes);
                dos.writeInt(Zone);
                dos.writeInt(dst);

               System.out.println(Zip+"\t"+City+"\t"+State+"\t"+Longitude+"\t"+Latitudes+"\t"+Zone+"\t"+dst+"\n");

            }

         }catch(Exception e){
                // if any I/O error occurs
                e.printStackTrace();
             }finally{

                // releases any associated system files with this stream
                if(is!=null)
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                if(dis!=null)
                    try {
                        dis.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }   
   } 

 }}
```

Comment: If you want to load file one after another why are you using Threads?

Comment: Loading files is going to be I/O bound, there is no point in performing a parallel read, I think. Especially if you then want to output them sequentially.

Comment: Adding to, and generalizing what's already been said, if task A and task B always happen together, but you can't _start_ task B until you have _finished_ task A, then it makes no sense to do the tasks in separate threads.  If this is an exercise to learn about threads, then it's a bad example because it's completely contrary to what threads are meant for.  Synchronizing threads is a necessary evil.  Your goal should always be to solve the problem using the least amount of synchronization that you can get away with and still guarantee that the program will do the Right Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options,

1. You can use [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)
2. You can use a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) to synchronize your threads.
3. A [Single thread executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) with a large enough queue(7) to satisfy your need.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the Thread class, you need to call join() in order to synchronize the threads:

```
Thread1.start();
Thread1.join();
Thread2.start();
Thread2.join();
Thread3.start();
Thread3.join();
...
```

You could change you main loop to

```
for (int l=1;l<8;l++ )  
   {
    thread1111 x = new thread1111(file+l+".dat");
    // threadList.add(x);
    x.start();
    x.join()
    }
```

Then the loop will not iterate to the next thread until the current thread is finished - Of course you could put this entire loop into its own thread

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            service.execute(new Runner("File" + i, lock));
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }

}

class Runner implements Runnable {
    String fileName;
    ReentrantLock lock;

    public Runner(String name, ReentrantLock lock) {
        this.fileName = name;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("Current Thread: "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Executing file: "
                + fileName);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

}
```

Put your code inside run method of Runnable class to print data of file and change it as per your own need.